# perform class method on class parameter

Tags: objective-c, class, methods

How can I perform a class method on a class passed to a method?

Let's say I have a class:

```
@interface MyClass:NSOBject
+ (NSArray *) array;
@end
```

When I instantiate the class

```
MyClass test = [[MyClass alloc] init;
```

I can access the array by

```
[[test class] array];
```

but if I pass this class to a method

```
[doStuffWithMyClass: (Class) aClass];
```

how can I access the arry within the method? can I "cast" class to a certain class?

```
- (NSInteger) doStuffWithMyClass: (Class) aClass {
   return [aClass array].count;
}
```

Comment: just forgot to edit this part of my question. for further information: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar

Answer (score 0):

`Class`es are objects, so yes, you can cast them.

Otherwise you can just do

```
[aClass performSelector:@selector(array)];
```

Comment: have you tried to just call the method? Do you get a compiler warning/error? Does it work?

Comment: how is this any better than `[aClass array]`?